# how to encrypt an install unecrypted fedora installation with LVM

Tags: fedora, disk-encryption, lvm, luks

Now I know that you can choose to encrypt your system in the fedora installation options,but I have already installed my system and I want to encrypt it without loosing data and I do not know how to do that,so far I have found no docs on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions here due to lack of context and info in the question:

Assumptions:

- Using Default LVM deployment offered by the auto partitioner.
- Assuming you mean root partition (/) and possibly most or all additional essential `system partitions`
- Access to an additional disk/storage pool sufficient to hold all present data.

Step 1) Backup anything in /home and anywhere else that is valuable/irreplaceable.

Step 2) Using a live installer,  either:

- wipe the present LVM install partitions and recreate.

  **(LUKS over LVM)**

  1)  take your lvm partitions and encrypt with `sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdXY`, where XY is replaced with sda1 or whatever your setup maps to. Rinse and repeat for all desired partitions.

  2) re-copy over the previously backup-ed info to the respective partitions.

  **(LVM over LUKS)**

  1) `sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdXY` with the same replacements, and then `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXY Fedora` where "Fedora" can be any name that the opened luks container will be named.

  2) create your desired LVM layout ***OR***  Allow the installer to provide a GUI partitioning option (in Fedora that is LVM over luks when using encryption).

  3) re-copy back over any data to it's respective new encrypted home.

Comment: of course you can do that, I was asking if there was another way

Comment: Not really,especially if data sanity and integrity are paramount